# EditText onTouch called more than once

Tags: android

I have an EditText that I attached `onTouchListener` to it:

```
m_outputField.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
```

Now I see that `onTouch` is called 3 times for every actual touch(click):

```
class MyTouchClickListener implements View.OnTouchListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        //do something

        return true;
    }

}
```

I guess that I am doing something wrong here, how to fix it (or at least ignore the second and third calls)?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check what actions you get for every touch(`event.getAction()`)?

Comment: if you want the button to be clicked just once why not use button.setOnClickListener(); ?

Comment: Because it's called only when EditText has focus.

Comment: Thanks! I needed this question answered for a `VideoView`, therefore I had to use `OnTouchListener`, no other listener would do for that. So I'm glad you found an answer. It worked for me too. My touch listener was getting called 3 times, no idea why. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
class MyTouchClickListener implements View.OnTouchListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            //do something
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this problem, replace your `setOnClickListener()` from editText to `setOnFocusChangeListener()`.

```
yourEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
           // Do Something Here..
        }
    }
});
```